# The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine in iis7

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle, iis

I have install oracle 11g express edition and enable IIS in my victual machine.
I created a web site in iis and put my source code into the location.
everything work perfectly fine UNTIL i upload excel file which I am using

```
provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0
```

And

```
provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0
```

Therefor I need to enable 32 bit application, so I do configuration from IIS --> application --> advanced settings/ As screen below I change enable 32 bit application to true.

[image]

after that when I try to re log in to my system. it throw me the error.

The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine

and it pointing to conn.Open() in my .cs file.

anyone has any idea how to solve this? Thanks!!!

[image]

Comment: The Oracle Instant client does not include OraOLEDB.Oracle provider. You have to download and install it separately.

Comment: @Wernfried any idea what kind of software we can download? I encounter this issues as well.

Comment: @LstPatrick, you an download them from here: [32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html), resp. [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)